# PWA routing and deep linking SPA or no SPA, framework or no framework

Tags: javascript, angular, polymer, aurelia, progressive-web-apps

SUMMARY: How to handle navigation, history and deep-linking in a PWA without using a heavy JS Framework ?

While leading a team to convert an existing shopping site form Angular 1 SPA to a Multi Page App (MPA) PWA I am stuck with some of the design decisions where I need little help as PWA is a fairly new concept (for me & my team).

My understanding so far is that we can totally avoid any framework and go with plain old javascript and service workers and split the SPA into MPA hence adding the benefit of splitting up resources needed on each page and not having to download a huge js file needed for the SPA to work.

The point where we are stuck is the ability to handle routing and deep linking with browser history API so that every part of a page has a unique URL and can be bookmarked.

We can surely manage that using fetch calls, updating only parts of the page with JS and pushing the browser state to history, but that seems like a lot of work and we should not be doing this in 2018.

Is there already some approach/library/pattern in the wild that has addressed this issue?

We looked into using react-router(using in other apps) or aurelia (small size) or polymer [sorry angular, you died under your own weight] but that seems like killing the very basic idea of PWA by adding a lot of code just to handle navigation.

Any thoughts?

Note: In case it is relevant, 90% of the app's target audience is on a slow network(~3G).

Comment: And with 3G you also mean some low cost Android devices?

Answer (score 3):

With you concern, I would like to break it down to three parts to discuss:

1."The point where we are stuck is the ability to handle routing and deep linking with browser history API so that every part of a page has a unique URL and can be bookmarked." - SSR support

If you want to build a website properly (saying converting from your SPA), with SEO support, social media sharing features, you will need to do some extra work for SSR (Server-side rendering) and generate static web pages. If you use React framework, you can look at:

- [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) (Great for most of applications need SSR)
- [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) (Great for static websites like blogs, news etc)
- [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) (You may need this library if your project starts from create-react-app or some boilerplate without SSR)

2."My understanding so far is that we can totally avoid any framework and go with plain old javascript and service workers and split the SPA into MPA hence adding the benefit of splitting up resources needed on each page and not having to download a huge js file needed for the SPA to work." - PWA and framework options.

You don't need any framework if PWA is the goal you are looking for. You can have multiple services workers managing different parts / modules of your website with different scopes (for example, '/users/' and '/products/' pages). But you need to do this carefully as my experience to debug multiple service workers is a nightmare.

And cache the app shell (bundle, css, images etc) of each part separately. Then, you can choose IndexDB to manage the data from your API and create proper indexes.

[Google Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) is also a great tool for PWA with a lot of features and can save you tons of time config your service worker.

3. "Note: In case it is relevant, 90% of the app's target audience is on a slow network(~3G)." - Caching strategy

In this case, you may need to consider your caching strategy before designing PWA. I would suggest to go with "Cache first, then network". So your users will at least have something to look at even the network is slow, under Lie-fi or offline.

Here is a great article from Jake Archibald: https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/ with different caching strategies.

Answer (score 0):

If the primary requirement is the ability to have deep link to every section of the app, to the extend that everything is bookmark-able, [Aurelia router](https://aurelia.io/docs/routing/) with its child router makes it very bookmarking friendly. For the concerns of slow network requirement, probably after the first download, it's should be like @MattYao stated already.